# Gateway 400 Bad Request Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, ubuntu-20.04

I am first time setup this stack (nginx , uwsgi, django application).

Currently I quite blurred on what i doing now, i hope someone can give me some guidelines.
This is the documentation i following.
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

What i managed to do is I can access my web app via uwsgi in virtualenv.

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module folio.wsgi:application
```

What stopping me right now is after i start nginx, when i access 192.168.92.148:8001, i got 400 Bad Request. Below are my files.

ifconfig

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.92.148  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.92.255
        inet6 fe80::b9d9:2ea2:a116:9c31  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:75:cf:c6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 391924  bytes 349216106 (349.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 218500  bytes 65221010 (65.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

folio_nginx.conf file

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

server {
    listen      8001;
    server_name 192.168.92.148;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   

    location /static {
        alias /home/yao1122/Project/folio/folio/static; 
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/yao1122/Project/folio/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

uwsgi_params file

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Can anyone please explain which part i have done wrongly? 
Or is there any log files i use for debug?

Thank you everyone for reading this.

Comment: Your WSGI server runs on port 8000 but your upstream is set to port 8001.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. thanks for quick reply. 
No, i stopped WSGI server after i success ran in virtual server. I just proving my WSGI can run correctly in my virtual server.

Currently i have no idea how to link nginx to uwsgi. and What are the content i should include in uwsgi params?

Comment: Well, as implied earlier: the upstream needs to be `127.0.0.1:8000`.